# How can i create a circle which has a number in?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm programming an Android game using AndEngine. I want to create a circle which has a number in, like in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Something like this:

circle.xml (in res/drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#aaf" />

</shape>
```

and circletext.xml (in res/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowRadius="10.0"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I added the following properties to TextView to add better polish for bigger numbers.      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="14dp"
        android:minWidth="14dp"
        android:maxHeight="14dp"

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess the simplest way is to just put a picture like that in haha. You could always use an image with a circle then layer the text with the number over the top of it.

Comment: i will create a lot.so i can't use images for good performance.

Comment: You could use a simple game engine to handle the images. They shouldnt be processor intensive then if they arent moving. Even then, most engines can handle 20 or 30 moving sprites without a problem, even with a collision system applied to all of them.

Comment: using an texture whose source is a bitmap will not impact your performance any more than using a texure who's source is an bitmap drawn from paint. In fact they will be the same. Because in order to display the circle in GL it must be a bitmap first.