# How to change TextView's background color dynamically?

Tags: android, textview, background-drawable

I have reffered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096851/how-can-i-create-a-circle-which-has-a-number-in) and implemented circular background for TextView using `circle.xml`  (in res/drawable) and setting it as `android:background="@drawable/circle"` for TextView. But what I need is , I need to set the background color dynamically through code. Just like the lollipop contacts app as shown below

[image]

How can I acheive this? I need the TextView background in circular shape always as shown in above image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change TextView background color in many ways like:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f44336"));
```

or

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
```

or

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.red_color));
```

and many other ways too...

**Edit:**

If you want to change your TextView background color that was defined in your drawable file, do it like this:

*GradientDrawable:*

```
GradientDrawable tvBackground = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground();
tvBackground.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f44336"));
```

*StateListDrawable:*

```
StateListDrawable tvBackground = (StateListDrawable) textView.getBackground();
tvBackground.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#f44336"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

But if you don't want to set a color filter, you can get the drawable of each state separately by following the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864337/how-can-i-change-colors-in-my-statelistdrawable).

Comment: Yeah, all these are options one could use to achieve the desired effect. I was just about adding the rest.

Comment: But this doesn't give me the circular background shape. it changes only the background color. The circle background will be gone and the new color will be shown in square background

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that you want it to be in a circular shape.

Comment: GradientDrawable does not work for TextView.  Getting error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Comment: @drod It seems that you are using StateListDrawable instead of GradientDrawable. StateListDrawable can have many background states thus no definite background. So try my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a one liner for this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted to ask how to generate random color to set as your textview background. Well, there are many ways. e.g;

```
textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255), (int) (Math.random() * 255)));
```

Comment: Ya. but this doesn't work for generating random color. `new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000))` this statement is invalid

Answer (score 1):

My text view has a circle shape defined as

// circleshape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:shape="oval"> 
<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" /> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp" android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/> 
</shape>
```

I applied it to Textview using `background="@drawable/circleshape"`

This makes the textview circular. Now use the code below to

```
GradientDrawable tvBackground = (GradientDrawable) viewHolder.userInitialsText.getBackground();

//myHexColorCode  is like "0xff00ff"
tvBackground.setColor(Color.parseColor(myHexColorCode));
```